# Remote Web3 connection to Parity node running on AWS

Tags: web3js, parity, nethereum

I have an Amazon EC2 instance set up running a Parity node. I'm trying to communicate with it via Web3 (using Nethereum.Web3 in C#).

If I connect locally with http://127.0.0.1:8545, everything works great.

If I try to connect from a different EC2 instance using http://somePrivateIP:8545, the RPC request fails to connect.

If I try to connect from my home PC using http://somePublicIP:8545, the RPC request also fails to connect.

I have enabled ALL traffic on TCP 8545 in the AWS security group.

I am starting Parity with everything relevant I can think of enabled:

C:\Program Files\Parity\Parity\ptray.exe --jsonrpc-apis all --jsonrpc-hosts all --jsonrpc-interface all

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it work if you enable `--unsafe-expose`? Edit: it's not `ptray.exe` but `parity.exe`.

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: I switched to using Infura for the node in the end