# Cannot Connect to Parity Public Node

Tags: parity

Quick question...

... I'm trying to run a Parity public node but cannot connect to it from any computer other than the one it's running on.

Parity v1.8.6 on
Windows 10 x64 - all updates

When I open 127.0.0.1:8180 from the computer it's running on I get the UI, no issues.
When I try to connect from any other computer on my LAN to 192.168.1.4:8180 I get:

> This site can’t be reached
>   192.168.1.4 refused to connect.

Parity is fully sync'd and I have no firewalls running on any of the computers.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting to a port which is only listening on loop back interface, not exposed to the network. See https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Wallet-Remote-Access

Comment: I've seen that page before... running in Windows, I wasn't sure how to run an SSH server. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: How about this question and the comment? Does it solve your problem?

 https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28753/remote-web3-connection-to-parity-node-running-on-aws?rq=1

Comment: Alright, so it looks like I have the SSH tunneling setup properly. I can connect to the Host now by tunneling 8180, 8545 and 8546 through the SSH tunnel. Now however, on the server I'm seeing messages like "Blocked connection from chrome extension://<bunch of letters> using invalid token."     Anyone know how to resolve?

Comment: Maybe related to incorrect CORS settings, just a wild guess.